# How match substring ignoring case in erlang

Tags: erlang, ets

How I can find in ETS table by a string that ignore upper/lower case?

This code find by a string starting with `wo`:

```
ets:test_ms({"WORD"}, [{{"wo"++'_'}, [], ['$_']}])
```

But, like `WORD` is upper case, nothing is returned.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is not a support for the case-insensitive matching in match spec (or matching in Erlang generally). You have basically three options there.

1. Generate all cases

   ```
   [{{"wo"++'_'}, [], ['$_']}, {{"wO"++'_'}, [], ['$_']}, {{"Wo"++'_'}, [], ['$_']}, {{"WO"++'_'}, [], ['$_']}]
   ```
2. Use guard expression (for longer words because the number of combinations is 2^N)

   ```
   [{{['$1','$2'|'_']},
     [{'orelse',{'=:=','$1',$w},{'=:=','$1',$W}},
      {'orelse',{'=:=','$2',$o},{'=:=','$2',$O}}],
     ['$_']}]
   ```
3. Transform data in `ets` table using `string:casefold/1` and search by this key.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This way I imagined it, but I thought there was another one capable of covering a greater number of generic cases. I believe that for this type of situation, it is necessary to use a relational database or other type of storage and not ETS.